# Getting last URL visited issue

Tags: magento-1

This is how I got my last URL:

```
 $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
```

For some reason the result of the `var_dump($url)` is  `/cms/index/noRoute/default/images/`. Afther I press several times ctrl+shift+r button , to clear the browser I got the right URL. Why ? I removed all files from var/cache/ and I got the same result. Thx in advance for any idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the referer from the request and if it exists and is not an external URL, use it. If not, fall back to the base URL.

```
$url = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) !== 0) && (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) !== 0))
{
    $url = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
```

Hope this will help you.